# Standard Python function to build a dictionary out of two, where the values from the first one are linked to the keys of the seconds?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a standard Python function to build a dictionary out of two, where the values from the first one are linked to the keys of the seconds?

```
dict_1= {'sparrow': 'cat', 'mouse': 'cat', 'deer': 'wolf'}  # prey: predator
dict_2 = {'cat': 'rural', 'wolf': 'forest'}  # predator: predator_habitat 
# my solution using a dictionary comprehension
{key: dict_2[val] for key, val in dict_1.items()}
# gives
{'sparrow': 'rural', 'mouse': 'rural', 'deer': 'forest'}  # prey: predator_habitat
```

Since the dictionaries can have million of records, computation time (and efficient code) matters.
Trying to adopt a solution to this [similar but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929358/build-a-new-dictionary-from-the-keys-of-one-dictionary-and-the-values-of-another)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(zip(dict_1.keys(), dict_2.values()))
# gives a un-wanted result:
{'cat': 'cat', 'wolf': 'cat'}
```

Note: I do not want to merge the dictionaries into on, keeping the key:value relations like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression).

Comment: No standard function for what it probably not a common operation. Your dictionary comprehension seems short and clear enough that there would be little benefit trying to do anything else. I think though you meant to say your solution is `{key: dict_2[val] for key, val in dict_1.items()}` (you switched the dictionaries in your post)

Comment: @Duncan yes, I accidentelly switshed the dictionaries - thank you!